# Does MediaExtractor support Http live stream?

Tags: android

as per Documentation we can give Http URL to MediaExtractor API as a data source.
[Click here for doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) My question is, Can we give Http Live Stream as a data source to MediaExtractor? for example

```
MediaExtractor mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
mediaExtractor.setDataSource("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qybUFnY7Y8w");//this works fine
```

But what about with live streams?

```
MediaExtractor mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
mediaExtractor.setDataSource("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8");//Does it work?
```